# .net core API Post get basic authentication

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I am trying to convert a program to .net core  from HttpListener. The old code works fine.
My old code that works.

```
    private readonly HttpListener listener;
    public void Start()
    {
        if (listener.IsListening)
            return;

        listener.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < HandlerThread; i++)
        {
            listener.GetContextAsync().ContinueWith(ProcessRequestHandler);
        }
    }
    private async void ProcessRequestHandler(Task<HttpListenerContext> result)
    {
        var context = result.Result;

        ResponseMessage response = new ResponseMessage();
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
            Console.WriteLine(identity.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(identity.Password);

        }
    }
```

My new code but I can't seem to find the username and password. This is the default asp.net core 7 app.  I do get my incoming message but everything I have done checking USER is null.

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string> >Post()
    {
         


        var remoteIpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

         
       


        var stream    = Request.Body ;
        string requestMessage;

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            requestMessage = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();


        return Ok("");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I did find this website that did work.  Is there a simple way not having to add all the extra code?
https://dotnetthoughts.net/implementing-basic-authentication-in-minimal-webapi/

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I found a easier way. Not saying better...

```
        [HttpGet("{msg}")]

    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string msg)
    {
        var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {

            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var token = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();

                var credentialstring = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(token));
                var credentials = credentialstring.Split(':');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic 
             realm=\"xxxx.com\"");
            return Unauthorized("\"Invalid Authorization Header\"");

        }



        return Ok("");
    }
```

I would love to have feedback to see if it can be improved on.